# Convert Ascii "1" to hex thats non printable and cannot be seen on network traffic

Tags: java, hex, ascii, non-printable, non-printing-characters

again another question about Ascii to hex conversion. I would like to take an Ascii "1" symbol that has been input by the user, then take that value, convert it to hex and send it over a network as its non printable value so that it cannot be easily read by anyone viewing the data on the network. Now i can take the hex value and send it over the network but when i sniff the network to view the data being transferred then I can read the hex value as it is. How would I make it so it appears as a non printable? I am using wireshark to view network data

Comment: Your question is inherently, completely, meaningless.  Networks transfer bytes, not characters.  There is no such thing as a "hidden" or "unprintable" byte.

Comment: Okay what is '1's non-printable value, enquiring minds want to know.

Comment: If you want to hide your data, use SSL.  (or figure out how to manage keys and prevent MITM)

Comment: What's the reason for doing something like this anyway? Doesn't smell right.

Comment: Please reformulate your question, you can propose some practical example by referring to http://ascii.cl/ 's codes. Do you want send one of its 128 chars? Or do you want send "control chars" (http://bit.ly/1fEkd7E)?

Comment: sorry about this, maybe i've not worded my question very well. I basically want to do hex key encryption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use real encryption and decryption between your source and destination (implementation will vary depending on how you are sending the data) or just obfuscate a bit by adding a known  value to the hex that is 'only' known by the source and destination (probably best to modulo this by 127) - essentially this is a shift cypher. This isn't very secure but makes it a little harder to read by packet sniffing. If you want a bit more obfuscation you could have a map of the 128 possibilities to 128 different. It all depend how 'secure' this connection need to be.